# udev power_supply rules not triggering

Tags: shell-script, udev

I know this seems to be the most commonly asked question about `udev` on here, but I believe I've done everything correctly and yet my rules still never get triggered. The script is executable and works perfectly when executed from the command line manually. (Ubuntu 15.04)

The script is supposed to be simple: dim the screen when the power supply is unplugged and bring it back to full brightness when it's plugged in. Here are the rules (in a file named `80-power_supply.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT}=="1", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/powermonitor.sh up"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT}=="0", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/powermonitor.sh down"
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness";

if [ "$1"  = "up" ]; then
    echo "937" > $FILE;
fi

if [ "$1" = "down" ]; then
    echo "92" > $FILE;
fi
```

If I run the script manually with the `up` or `down` arguments it works perfectly. But when I disconnect my power supply or reconnect it, nothing happens.

Comment: I also tried making `ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT}==1` in case it didn't like the strings, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: did you do `udevadm control --reload`. To debug, run `udevadm monitor` to see the events passing.

Comment: Yeah, I restarted the system and tried `udeevadm control --reload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT}` to `ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}`.

`POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT` does not change on connect/disconnect and for that reason was the wrong environment variable to be testing.

`POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE` changes from 1 to 0 when removed from AC Adapter power and therefore is consistently measurable.